# How can I study the continuity of this function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with compact support; is the function
$$F(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}dx\bigg(f(x)\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z}|x|}}{4\pi|x|}\bigg)$$ continuous in the set
$$Q=\lbrace{z: \Re z\in [a,b], \Im z\in (0,1]\rbrace}$$ ?
I write
$$F(z)-F(z')=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}dx\bigg(f(x)\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z}|x|}}{4\pi|x|}\bigg)-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}dx\bigg(f(x)\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z'}|x|}}{4\pi|x|}\bigg)$$ so that
$$|F(z)-F(z')|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}dx\bigg|\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z'}|x|}-e^{i\sqrt{z'}|x|}}{4\pi|x|}\bigg||f(x)|$$ and with the theorem of dominated convergence I obtain the continuity. Is this reasoning right?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, but I would recast the problem in more general terms, to abstract 
away inessential details. Let $M$ be such that $f(x)$ vanishes for $|x|>M$.

*Step 1.* For every $R$ there exists $L=L(R,M)$ such that the function $\psi_x(\xi)=\exp(i\xi |x|)$ 
is $L$-Lipschitz in the set $D_R=\{\xi:|\xi|\le R\}$.

Proof: the first derivative in $\xi$ is uniformly bounded.

*Step 2.* The function $g(x)=f(x)/|x|$ is integrable.

Proof: Cauchy-Schwarz.

*Step 3.* If $g$ is integrable on some set $X$ and for every $x\in X$ the function $\psi_x $ is $L$-Lipschitz,
then the integral $\int g(x)\psi_x(\xi)\,dx$ is a Lipschitz function of  $\xi$.

Proof:
$$\left|\int g(x)\psi_x(\xi_1)\,dx - \int g(x)\psi_x(\xi_2)\,dx \right| \le 
L|\xi_1-\xi_2| \int |g(x)|\,dx
$$

Conclusion: with $\xi$ in place of $\sqrt{z}$ your function is Lipschitz in $\xi$. The rest boils
down to handling the  square root.

Comment: I've read your answer. So youo reasoning is valid for $\xi\in\mathbb{C}$ too?

Comment: @Sue Yes. But the presence of square root in your function does not allow one to take the entire plane at once.

Comment: I post my comment as an answer because I don't succed in leaving it as a "comment".
@5pm I consider the function in the set $Q$ so I should have no problems, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there are no problems with the square root on your set. You could not leave a comment because this is now your second account. There is an account merge tool here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help